# How to remove default TTS Playback/Audio in HERE Maps

Tags: here-api

I am working for the first time with a `turn-by-turn` application using HERE API. I am following the instruction recommended in the [Guide - HERE SDK](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-voice-instructions.html), and so far, so good. Nevertheless, I am not able to remove the default `TTS` Playback/Audio that the SDK offers.

I thought that, as mentioned in the [Audio Management](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/audio-management.html) section, by implementing `AudioPlayerDelegate` class and calling `NavigationManager.AudioPlayer.setDelegate(AudioPlayerDelegate)` all audio and text-to-speech playback by the SDK would be stopped, but it keeps triggering them. I make copy of my code example:

**FragmentView.java**

```
public class FragmentView {
     private NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener instructListener
        = new NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener() {

     private AudioPlayerDelegate m_audioPlayerDelegate = new AudioPlayerDelegate() {
    @Override
    public boolean playText(final String audioCue) {
        m_activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    playAudioCue(fileName, 1);

                Toast.makeText(m_activity, "TTS output: " + audioCue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "TextToSpeech: " + audioCue);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean playFiles(String[] strings) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Play files");
        return false;
    }
};


     private void addNavigationListeners() {

    m_navigationManager.addNavigationManagerEventListener(
            new WeakReference<NavigationManager.NavigationManagerEventListener>(
                    m_navigationManagerEventListener));

    m_navigationManager.addPositionListener(
            new WeakReference<NavigationManager.PositionListener>(m_positionListener));


    m_navigationManager.addNewInstructionEventListener(
            new WeakReference<NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener>(instructListener));

    m_navigationManager.addPositionListener(
            new WeakReference<NavigationManager.PositionListener>(positionListener));

    m_navigationManager.getAudioPlayer().setDelegate(m_audioPlayerDelegate);
}

}
```

The code is already working. No error is triggered or shown. My problem is that I can not use my own `TextToSpeech` engine until the default one has finished. I would like to get rid of the default one, and I thought that by delegating a new `AudioPlayerDelegate` would do it automatically but I was wrong. How could I do it?

**NOTE**

I do not want to remove the triggering of the events, but only the voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only error was that, in order to delegate, the method `playText` must return true. Documentation is mentioned bellow:

> playText()
>
> boolean playText(java.lang.String text) Delegate function for
>   NavigationManager.AudioPlayer used by NavigationManager. Clients will
>   receive a text string that can be submitted to TTS engines for
>   playback. Parameters: text - TTS text to be played. Returns: true if
>   client is handling the TTS playback, false will allow the SDK to
>   handle it.

Answer (score 0):

To stop currently played audio use

`NavigationManager.getAudioPlayer().stop(`)

use NavigationManager.setEnabledAudioEvents() to enable/disable audio events during navigation

For more details refer the following documentation : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/NavigationManager.AudioPlayer.html

Comment: According to the API, "Note: by delegating NavigationManager.AudioPlayer it immediately stops all current audio and TTS playbacks by the SDK". Should it not be automatically stopped when implementing setDelegate? At least, that was my intention. To delegate it, and to start using my own TTS Engine.

Comment: I have tried your proposal, but it stops triggering the events I do not want to hear. My intention for delegating was to have the same events but played with my own TTS. Does it work on this way?